# Pandas subtracting values of two data frames element wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

As part of an object constructor I want to subtract the values of two pandas data frames element wise:

```
        self.dfload=pd.read_csv(self.name +'/' + 'load.csv')                    
        self.dfload.set_index('snapshot', inplace=True)

                         load_1      load_2      load_3      load_4  
snapshot                                                              
2018-01-01 00:00:00   68.248569   91.998188   64.988923  139.535086   
2018-01-01 00:15:00  138.274243  127.186259   80.769227   33.509007   
2018-01-01 00:30:00  129.824298   56.706114   75.234845  138.610287   
2018-01-01 00:45:00   51.754610   45.703056   73.060490   36.913774   
2018-01-01 01:00:00   52.129775  139.315283   67.093788   60.488806
```

and

```
        self.dfsupply=pd.read_csv(self.name + '/' + 'supply.csv')               
        self.dfsupply.set_index('snapshot', inplace=True)

                      supply_1   supply_2   supply_3   supply_4     
snapshot                                                                     
2018-01-01 00:00:00  28.448017  45.383377  56.626144  40.044848    
2018-01-01 00:15:00  37.534878  29.094980  67.722537  15.002448    
2018-01-01 00:30:00  46.163805  28.324557  26.322953  23.250904     
2018-01-01 00:45:00  48.192774  55.049855  72.872200  21.602035     
2018-01-01 01:00:00  60.499436  53.698329  74.674572  42.425620
```

by

```
self.dfresidualLoad=self.dfsupply.subtract(self.dfload, axis='column')
```

The result is NaN for each element and the concatenation of the two dfs:

```
                         load_1  load_2  load_3  ...  supply_1  supply_2 ...
snapshot                                                                        
2018-01-01 00:00:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
.
.
```

There is no issue by subtracting single columns from each other. Unfortunately this is not the ideal solution since I want to keep the number of columns undefined.

Comment: Make sure shapes, index and columns are equals then subtraction will work elementwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If same columns names and index in both DataFrames subtract numpy array created by second `DataFrame`:

```
self.dfresidualLoad=self.dfsupply - self.dfload.values
```

Or use `rename` columns if positions of columns names matched:

```
d = dict(zip(dfload.columns, dfsupply.columns))
df = dfsupply.subtract(dfload.rename(columns=d), axis='column')
print (df)
                       supply_1   supply_2   supply_3    supply_4
2018-01-01 00:00:00  -39.800552 -46.614811  -8.362779  -99.490238
2018-01-01 00:15:00 -100.739365 -98.091279 -13.046690  -18.506559
2018-01-01 00:30:00  -83.660493 -28.381557 -48.911892 -115.359383
2018-01-01 00:45:00   -3.561836   9.346799  -0.188290  -15.311739
2018-01-01 01:00:00    8.369661 -85.616954   7.580784  -18.063186
```